# MS Access Go to control on subform

Tags: ms-access

I have a data entry form where two of the fields are contained in a subform within the main form. We are using barcode scanners to enter data. These barcodes essentially press enter after every scan, however sometimes our barcodes are damaged and, when scanned, can sometimes add random special characters. When ever someone scans a barcode in the "Part Number" field that contains any of the following characters (+, #, %, =) i have a msgbox that pops up alerting the person scanning that the barcode didn't read correctly. After the message pops up I want to refocus on the "Part Number" field so that they can rescan the barcode or just type the data manually (if the barcode keeps being buggy) rather than having to click back in to that field, deleting the wrong data, then re entering the data. My code is below:

```vb
Private Sub Part_Number_LostFocus()
Dim RegEx As Object, MyString As String, Answer As Integer
Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
MyString = [Forms]![frmInventoryCountEntry]![tblInventoryCount subform].Form![Part Number]
With RegEx
    .Pattern = "[+#%=]+"
End With
If RegEx.Test(MyString) = True Then
    MsgBox "Part Number Contains Invalid Character", vbOKOnly
    DoCmd.GoToControl "tblInventoryCount subform"
    DoCmd.GoToControl "Part Number"
```

I've tried set focus as well and no matter what the cursor always goes to the next field rather than refocusing on the "Part Number" field. I'm sure the solution is simple but I've tried a bunch of different things and I'm starting to get frustrated :( can anyone help me out? Btw, I'm using access 2003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `.SetFocus`?

You might also consider using a Before Update event and then cancelling if the string contains those symbols. That way the focus never leaves the Part Number control.

Comment: I did try .setfocus and that didn't work, but putting my code in Before Update worked. However, when I troubleshoot and put in a part containing one of the invalid characters I get the following message: "The value violates the validation rule for the field or record". I do have a validation rule for this field which is it won't except data with <4 characters, but the data i used to troubleshoot the code doesn't violate that validation rule. Any idea why I'm getting this message?

Comment: When does the error message appear? After the event is cancelled? If so you might be able to avoid it with a `me.undo` beforehand. Just a guess.

Comment: It comes up when i type in a part number with an invalid character then press enter to go to the next field. So yea after the event is cancelled

Comment: Interestingly, I added two lines of code at the end of the sub to highlight the text in that field:                   
    Me![part number].SelStart = 0
    Me![part number].SelLength = Len(Me![part number])                                                       and the error message disappeared. Do you have an idea as to why that happened?

Comment: Sorry no. I'm not able to replicate the error on my end. Is there still a lost focus event triggering after the before update event is cancelled?